# VS2010 SP1 WPF designer crashes, without SP1 it's working

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

Setup:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
- Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- WPF Application targetting .NET 3.5 SP1
- Uses Infopath FormControl
- No add-ins on VS2010

Problem:
First open any window or usercontrol in Visual Studio designer and it opens normally. Then simply click on xaml source (I'm using split view, xaml and the "actual control") and the designer will crash almost immediately with the following exception:

[System.Reflection.Adds.UnresolvedAssemblyException]
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Adapter, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.

I looked from GAC and the assembly is there (processor architecture is MSIL).

What's going on in here? No help from Google. Funny thing is that without VS2010 SP1 everything works just fine...

### Update

I tried VS2010 repair from the dvd and SP1 reinstall but it didn't help. However, I was able to narrow it down. If I remove the reference to Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.FormControl from the project it works fine. So why does the FormContol crash the designer on **every** WPF window and usercontrol and only with VS2010 SP1?

Office 2007 Repair didn't help either.

Comment: what is the version of office that you have (2007/2010)?

Comment: Office 2007 Enterprise with SP2 + latest updates from Windows Update

Comment: This seems to be reported as a bug in Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651966/system-reflection-adds-unresolvedassemblyexception-in-wpf-xaml-designer-after-vs2010-sp1#tabs

Comment: I guess you will need to rollback VS SP1 to continue working until there is a fix.

Comment: Experiencing the same thing with FluentNHibernate referenced, so obviously there must be some pattern there, but only from certain file locations. Here's a link that describes our issue quite well : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/680777/wpf-designer-unhalted-invalidoperationexception-all-over - obviously MS have no intention to fix this for VS 2010. I haven't read anything to proof me wrong so far in my guess that this occurs on 64Bit machines only.

Comment: I also had a problem with crushing VS 2010 SP1 (and before applying SP1 everything was fine): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814466/why-my-user-control-crashes-visual-studio/12183787#12183787

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why my user control crashes Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814466/why-my-user-control-crashes-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

This Blog help me a lot hope this would help you also.
http://www.purelogic.ca/blog/matt/2010/10/13/visual-studio-2010-designer-exception-unresolvedassemblyexception.aspx

Comment: At first I thought it worked but designer started crashing after all.

Answer (score 0):

What about running the VS2010 repair? try repairing it from the original DVD and then re-install the SP1 over it.

That's my suggestion if you don't get an answer that explicitly solves your problem.

Comment: What about doing the same with Office? Repair will probably re-install the Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.FormControl assembly in the GAC.