# Why does my user control crash Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, user-controls

I've spent all day trying to figure out why this user control crashes VS2010 (Windows Phone 7.1 development). Application runs this control with no problem, but when I go to design mode in MainPage.xaml - VS crash.

```
<UserControl x:Class="blabla.Controls.Tile"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="SwitchSidesAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="FrontSide">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause1" KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="-90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause2" KeyTime="0:0:6.2" Value="-90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause3" KeyTime="0:0:6.4" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause4" KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackSide">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause5" KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause6" KeyTime="0:0:6.2" Value="90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause7" KeyTime="0:0:6.4" Value="90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause8" KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="90"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="FrontSide">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause9" KeyTime="0:0:6">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause10" KeyTime="0:0:6.4">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause11" KeyTime="0:0:12">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="FrontSide">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause12" KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause13" KeyTime="0:0:6.2" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause14" KeyTime="0:0:6.4" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MoveThisForPause15" KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Front side -->
        <Grid x:Name="FrontSide" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
              Background="{Binding FrontBackground}">
            <Image Source="{Binding FrontImage}" />
        </Grid>
        <!-- /Front side -->

        <!-- Back side -->
        <Grid x:Name="BackSide" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
              Background="{Binding BackBackground}">
            <Grid.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection RotationX="-90" />
            </Grid.Projection>
            <Image Source="{Binding BackImage}" />
        </Grid>
        <!-- /Back side -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And now the code.

```
namespace blabla.Controls
{
    public partial class Tile : UserControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Defines if the tile has two sides.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsTwoSided
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTwoSidedProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IsTwoSidedProperty, value);

                this.startAnimations();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Image that will be displayed on front side.
        /// </summary>
        public BitmapImage FrontImage
        {
            get { return (BitmapImage)GetValue(FrontImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FrontImageProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Image that ill be displayed on back side.
        /// </summary>
        public BitmapImage BackImage
        {
            get { return (BitmapImage)GetValue(BackImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackImageProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Brush that will be used as background for front side.
        /// </summary>
        public Brush FrontBackground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(FrontBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FrontBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Brush that will be used as background for back side.
        /// </summary>
        public Brush BackBackground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(BackBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTwoSidedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsTwoSided", typeof(bool), typeof(Tile), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FrontImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FrontImage", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(Tile), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackImage", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(Tile), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FrontBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FrontBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(Tile),
            new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"])));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(Tile),
            new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"])));

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public Tile()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /// <summary>
        /// Modifies animation frames' KeyTime to adjust time for new timing.
        /// <param name="pauseTime">Lenght of the pause.</param>
        /// </summary>
        private void setPauses(TimeSpan pauseTime)
        {
            // Sets pauses.
            EasingDoubleKeyFrame frameToModify;

            for(int i = 0; true; i++)
            {
                if(this.FindName("MoveThisForPause" + i) != null)
                {
                    frameToModify = (EasingDoubleKeyFrame)this.FindName("MoveThisForPause" + i);
                    frameToModify.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(frameToModify.KeyTime.TimeSpan - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) + pauseTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts animations.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="beginTime">Usually delay before first-time animation.</param>
        private void startAnimations()
        {
            // We start animations only if the tile is two sided.
            if(this.IsTwoSided)
            {
                // Stopping previous animation.
                this.SwitchSidesAnimation.Stop();

                // Sets correct pauses.
                this.setPauses(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(new Random().Next(5, 10)));

                // Starts animation.
                this.SwitchSidesAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(new Random().Next(2, 15));
                this.SwitchSidesAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                this.SwitchSidesAnimation.Begin();
            }
            else
            {
                this.SwitchSidesAnimation.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error messages or other symptoms to go by?

Comment: Could you remove this line and see what happens: `this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;`?

Comment: @HenkHolterman No, Luke Woodward found the problem.

Comment: @Erno Nothing, just binding doesn't work. ;-) In the end it seems that it wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce this crash, admittedly using the non-Phone version of Silverlight, and in Visual Web Dev Express as opposed to the full version of VS.

The problem ultimately comes down to the default values specified in these two dependency property declarations:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FrontBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FrontBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(Tile),
        new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"])));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BackBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(Tile),
        new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"])));
```

The crash went away after I replaced the default values with `null` (using Notepad++ as Visual Web Dev Express was crashing), deleted the project's `bin` and `obj` folders and restarted Visual Web Dev Express.  When I restarted VWDX, it complained that it couldn't find the type `Tile`, but that was because I had deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders.  A rebuild sorted that out.

I can only guess at exactly what the problem is.  At the point the `Tile` class is being statically initialized, `Application.Current` might be `null`, `Application.Current.Resources` might be `null`, or `Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"]` might be `null` (which would cause the cast to `Color` to fail, as `Color` is a `struct`).  Perhaps the VS designer doesn't handle very well exceptions thrown during static initialization of types?

Incidentally, I'd also like to point out another couple of potential problems.  Firstly, this is your `IsTwoSided` property:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines if the tile has two sides.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsTwoSided
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTwoSidedProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsTwoSidedProperty, value);

            this.startAnimations();
        }
    }
```

It looks like you want the `startAnimations` method to be called whenever your `IsTwoSided` dependency property changes.  The code you've written above will not achieve that.

When Silverlight changes the value of a dependency property, it doesn't call your the property setter to do this.  If you want things to happen when a dependency property's value changes, use a [property-changed callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903933(v=vs.95).aspx#metadata) instead.

Secondly, in `Tile.xaml`, you declare the `Storyboard` in `<UserControl.Resources>` as follows:

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="SwitchSidesAnimation">
```

I would recommend using `x:Key` instead of `x:Name`, for two reasons:

- all items within resource dictionaries (except implicit styles) must have an `x:Key` or an `x:Name` to identify them.  VS supports using `x:Name` in place of `x:Key`, but that exists as a [legacy support mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189012(v=vs.95).aspx) only.
- using `x:Name` in an element in a user-control XAML causes VS to create a field with that name in `InitializeComponent()` in the auto-generated part of your `Tile` class (in `Tile.g.cs` somewhere within obj\Debug).  However, just because you can stick `x:Name` on an element doesn't necessarily mean you'll be able to access the corresponding object in the generated field.  Because there is no UIElement named `SwitchSidesAnimation` in your `Tile.xaml` (Storyboards are not UIElements), the `SwitchSidesAnimation` field will always be `null`.

  Indeed, the [MSDN documentation for the x:Key attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189012(v=vs.95).aspx) (also linked to above) mentions that

  > A FindName call using a key value will not retrieve a keyed resource

  (`FindName` is the method used to look up a control by name.  If you look in `Tile.g.cs` you'll see it used there.)

I'd recommend always using `x:Key` within resource dictionaries so you're not led to believe that you can access this Storyboard directly in code-behind.

To access the storyboard in code-behind, use

```
    this.Resources["SwitchSidesAnimation"] as Storyboard
```

In fact, if you add the following property, you won't have to change your `startAnimations` method:

```
    private Storyboard SwitchSidesAnimation
    {
        get { return this.Resources["SwitchSidesAnimation"] as Storyboard; }
    }
```

Comment: Allright, seems that you correctly figured out, where the problem was. But after using property-changed callback the new problem emerges. Method for callback has to be static, right? (in this case it's startAnimations()). So I have to make startAnimations() static.

Comment: In startAnimations() I use SwitchSidesAnimation (I've created the property as you proposed) and to access it I have to make SwitchSidesAnimation static too. When this property is static I can't access usercontrol's resources through "this.Resources[xxx]". The same is with setPauses() (used in startAnimations()) - if I make it static I won't be able to access animation frames throught "this.Findname("MoveThisForPause9")"

Comment: Nevermind, I have to cast DependencyObject argument to Tile and I have my control's instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem (while developing Silverlight 5), which took me almost 3 days to struggle, and would take surely more, but luckily here I have found the solution (by Luke Woodward).

In my case I was using:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStyleProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MyStyle",
            typeof(Style), 
            typeof(MainButton), 
            new PropertyMetadata(
                    // using this construct as a default value 
                    // makes VS 2010 SP1 to crush!
                    Application.Current.Resources["SomeStyle"] as Style, 
                    OnPropertyChanged
            )
        );
```

So the common thing in both problems is using some resource value as a default value for DependencyProperty.

But what is more tragic, this problem occured only after I applied SP1 for VS 2010 (since I wanted to develop in Silverlight 5, which required SP1 for VS 2010).

This brought me headache and a lot of time to search.

Fortunately now it is solved now, thanks!