# WPF mess, crash visual studio 2010 hard crash when any xaml opened with WPF designer

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I am the new Architect for a very large WPF application. My main goal is performance, but my personal goal is the ability to view xaml in the WPF designer without a hard VS crash. We are currently editing xaml in xml editor, which is inefficient to say the least. I am totally clueless on what I can do to find the source/s of problem as VS does say much about why it's crashing. If anyone can kick my ass into the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Some facts to possibly help with solution.
We are using VS 2010 Premium
There are around 70 merged dictionary files.
We are using Telerik controls.
We are on .net 4
It is a primarily VB.Net application

Let me know if I can provide any other useful information.

Comment: Are you dependent on any native .dlls?  That can be a big source of problems for designers in VS.

Comment: The only way I've been able to reproduce a VS crash in the XAML Designer was as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11815248/), but this might not be of much help to you.  The only other thing I can suggest (which you may well already have tried) is deleting all the bin and obj folders and rebuilding.

Comment: mydogisbox:  yes, some days if feels like everything depends on everything. :)  I have tried creating a very simple xaml that does nothing in code-behind, and has only a textblock element. And it still crashed. :(

Comment: Luke: at your suggestion I tried to deleted all bin/obj folders. but it still crashes on a very simpler xaml.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the UserControl loaded event sometimes

```
private void connectionControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this) ==  false)
{
//act normally
}
}
```